# Open Layers 3 on https getting mixed display content for WMS requests

Tags: javascript, browser, openlayers-3, wms

I have an Open Layers 3 implementation which has to run on a secure server (https) because it includes a user login functionality.

However, many WMS data feeds are http and not https resulting in the browser blocking the content because of **mixed display content**.  For example:

[image]

Is there anyway that a https server running Open Layers 3 can display WMS data from http sources?  Is there an Open Layers or external workaround for this?

A typical OL3 call looks like this:

```
var layer_to_return = new ol.layer.Tile({
  preload: Infinity,
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
    url: 'http://apps.ecmwf.int/wms/',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'composition_aod550'},
    serverType: 'geoserver',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    }))
});
```

Which would work fine if it was actually https and not http.